# githash.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, file-not-found

I am installing Nxtrim (https://github.com/sequencing/NxTrim). However, after typing "make", I am getting following error:

```
make
g++ -O3  -I/galaxy/home/biomonika/boost_1_56_0/include  mergeReads.cpp fastqlib.o utilityfunc.o -o mergeReads   -L/galaxy/home/biomonika/boost_1_56_0/lib -lz -lboost_iostreams  -lboost_program_options
mergeReads.cpp:2:21: fatal error: githash.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mergeReads] Error 1
```

.cpp code indeed requires githash.h

```
#include "githash.h"
```

Where could I download this? It is not  distributed with my program as other required headers. Google doesn't seem to show many anwers..

Comment: The authors makefile is wrong as it tries to generate githash.h after compiling mergeReads.cpp. Better bug him about that.

Comment: Yeah, that makefile is just busted. It creates `githash.h` *after* in the body of a recipe that has a prerequisite that requires that file to exist.

Comment: I have just issued a ticket to report the problem. Thanks! Glad to know problem is not on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by moving generating githash.h in Makefile before the command requiring it. 
(As suggested by @nos and @Etan_Reisner